# Nginx conf for secure redirect except one subdomain

Tags: nginx

I've looked at the info here, and while my question is related, I have a more specific need.

- I have a domain, `example.com`.
- Any traffic to `http://example.com/xyz` should be routed to `https://example.com/xyz`
- Any traffic to `http://www.example.com/xyz` should be routed to `https://example.com/xyz`  (CNAME of www is in place on DNS side)
- However, any traffic to `http://dev.example.com` should NOT be routed to `https`, it should remain http and be redirected to an external server (which is already set up as CNAME on the DNS side)

In a nutshell, all traffic including www should be redirected to its secure https equivalent, with the exception of the `dev` subdomain. How should this be setup?

---

Adding the block in Nginx as it looks now:

```
    server {
            listen 9.9.9.9:80;
            server_name example.com ;
            return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
        }

    #    server {
    #        listen 9.9.9.9:80;
    #        server_name dev.example.com ;
    #        return 301 cname.createsend.com;
    #    }

    server {
        listen 443        ssl http2 deferred;
        listen [::]:443   ssl http2 deferred;

        server_name   example.com;
        root /home/example;

        ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;#

        include common.conf;
        include ssl.conf;

    }
```

---

The `ssl.conf` include above is like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/sVmtV6uP

Comment: Use a separate `server` block for `dev.example.com`.

Comment: Thank you. But if it's just a CNAME, what should be the instruction inside that block? It's not technically a 301 redirect.

Comment: `CNAME` or `A` record means nothing to `nginx`. It only uses the name that appears in the URL bar.

Comment: I understand that. What should I put inside the server block for `dev.example.com`? I cannot put a root folder or anything, because there is none. I also cannot put a rewrite/redirect rule. So do I create an empty subdomain block?

Comment: Are you saying that the CNAME does not point to this server?

Comment: My domain's CNAME points to an external service provider. So `dev.example.com` (where example.com is my DNS) points to some `something.totallydifferent.com`. On the destination, I have zero control.

Comment: So CNAME for `dev` points to some remote server. If you are experiencing redirection to `https` for no good reason, you probably have HTTP Strict Transport Security on `example.com` with `includeSubDomains` enabled.

Comment: Hi Richard. yes, the `ssl.conf` in my server block (now included in the question) does have this: `add_header  Strict-Transport-Security   "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains" always;`   -- I do want to include ssl.conf, but then I can override the add_header directive to un-include the `includeSubdomains`. How do I do this. Can I add a line `add_header  Strict-Transport-Security   "max-age=63072000" always;`  after including the ssl.conf ?

Comment: Here's my ssl.conf: https://pastebin.com/raw/sVmtV6uP

Comment: Please show the output of `curl -v http://dev.example.com`. You can use a different IP address in the output, but make sure to tell if it is the IP address of `example.com` or `something.totallydifferent.com`.

Comment: If you get a redirect to `https://dev.example.com` when you visit `http://dev.example.com`, then you either have HSTS settings that forces browser to load the site over https, or the `dev.example.com` server sends that redirect. You can find out this with the `curl` command above, or browser developer tools network tab.

Answer (score 0):

If your DNS set up is like this:

```
example.com     A     192.168.10.1
www.example.com A     192.168.10.1
dev.example.com CNAME someother.example.com
```

Here, `192.168.10.1` corresponds to your server where the site is running.

The https redirection happens either with 301 redirects, which are sent by each virtual host serving each domain. So, in this case, you need to have the redirect in the virtual server block for http protocol for `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

The server at `someother.example.com` is a separate entity, and on that server, you will configure normal HTTP server block.

This should meet your requirements.

However, if you have HSTS headers enabled for `example.com` which has `includeSubdomains` attribute set, then you need to remove that attribute. Otherwise browsers will automatically load https version of every subdomain, for example your `dev.example.com`.

If you already set HSTS headers for your domain with the attribute, you need to clear the HSTS entry from your browser for the domain before changing the setting.

Comment: Thank @TeroKilkanen. The `someother.example.com` is an external domain, and I have no control of it. This is how CNAMEs work, as you know. So do I need a `dev.example.com` block on my nginx at all, after removing the includeSubdomains directive?

Comment: You don't need such a block, since the domain is handled elsewhere.

Comment: That doesn't work. Because my example.com is forwarding to https://example.com. But only for dev.example.com, I do NOT wish to forward to the ssl version. Hence this whole question. I've added to my main post above the server block as it exists now -- what's wrong in this?